# How to deal with SQL Injection in OrientDB using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, orientdb, orientjs

I'm using the orientjs library to perform operations in the Orient Database. I read in the documentation that it's possible to use parameter-style queries like the following:

```
db.query(
   'SELECT name, ba FROM Player '
   + 'WHERE ba >= :ba AND team = ":team"',
   {params: {
      ba: targetBA,
      team: targetTeam }
   }, limit: 20
).then(function(hitters){
   console.log(hitters)
});
```

My question is: Is it enough to prevent SQL injection? Because I didn't find information about that in the NodeJS API. In the case of Java, there is a 'Prepared Query' concept, I'm not sure if they are refering to the same thing.

Comment: Parameterized queries generally prevents the possibility of SQL injections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems to be secure, I'm trying with this code (yours taken from the wiki is a bit buggy):

```
var name='admin';

db.open().then(function() {
    return db.query(
        "SELECT * FROM OUser "
        + "WHERE name = :name",
        {params:{
            name: name
            }
        });
}).then(function(res){
    console.log(res);
    db.close().then(function(){
        console.log('closed');
    });
});
```

First of all, the query is parsed as `SELECT * FROM OUser WHERE name = "admin"` (observed with the Studio Query Profiler).

As expected, I get the admin user record.

Since the params are evaluated directly as String, there's non need quote them (e.g. `:name` not `':name'`). So there is no way to inject something like `' OR '1'='1` or any `; drop something;`

---

Here are some test I did:

- `var name='; create class p;';`

  returns no records;

  evaluated by orient as: `SELECT * FROM OUser WHERE name = "; create class p;"`
- `var name="' OR '1'='1";`

  returns no records;

  evaluated as: `SELECT * FROM OUser WHERE name = "' OR '1'='1"`
- `var name='" OR "1"="1';`

  returns no records;

  evaluated as: `SELECT * FROM OUser WHERE name = "\" OR \"1\"=\"1"`
- quoting the param name in the query: `"WHERE name = ':name'"`

  evaluated as: `SELECT * FROM OUser WHERE name = ':name'`

---

Feel free to try more combinations, in my opinion seems quite safe.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think they should add a small section explaining that in their docs: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/OrientJS-Query.html